# Named Scope in Rails to order Record by number of associated Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

Im new to Rails. I have 2 nested resources: Photos and tags.

```
Photos
  Tags
end
```

Photos has many tags, and tag belongs to photo.

I want to create a scope that orders Photos by number of tags in them.
The relation they have is in Tags:

`t.integer  "photo_id"`with that column.

How should I make my scope If I want first the photos with most tags?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: scope :most_tagged, -> { order(:tags).reverse_order.count.limit(10) } , but the thing is tags is not a column for photos...so thats why I don't know how to link it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading some documentation about [belongs_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) and [has_one](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one) associations.

In particular interest to you may be the `:counter_cache` option for `belongs_to` in order to keep track of how many tags each photo has. This will also give you a column to sort (and index) by as well.

From there, it should be pretty trivial to create the scope you need from examples all over the internet.

Comment: Hi ! I added a column to Photos model named tags_count , integer type.
I also added a counter_cache: true to my Tag model. How am I supposed to make my scope now?

Comment: I did this:   scope :most_tagged, -> { order('tags_count desc') } , it's not giving an error but the order is not right. Should I reset my ddbb?

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with the recent versions Rails ActiveRecord syntax (I'm most familiar with 2.3), but I'd guess the syntax for the scope should be very similar to what you'd type for a raw query. Are the tag counts for every photo correct?